# Login to Kubernetes dashboard - Can't get the token - No resources found

Tags: login, kubernetes, dashboard, token

I successfully installed microk8s and I enabled the dashboard.

I land on the screen which is asking for config or token login. The problem is that I can't get this token. I've read trough many tutorials but they mostly follow the same approach which doesn't work for me.

Examples:

- https://jhooq.com/setting-up-kubernetes-dashboard/#kubernetes-dashboard-local-cluster
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/dashboard-tutorial.html

The problem is that I always get this "No resources found in kube-system namespace" error, so there is no way for me to get the token:

```
kadmin@kubernetes-master:~$ kubectl create serviceaccount k8sadmin -n kube-system
error: failed to create serviceaccount: serviceaccounts "k8sadmin" already exists

kadmin@kubernetes-master:~$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding k8sadmin --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:k8sadmin
error: failed to create clusterrolebinding: clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "k8sadmin" already exists

kadmin@kubernetes-master:~$ kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $(kubectl -n kube-system get secret | (grep k8sadmin || echo "$_") | awk '{print $1}') | grep token: | awk '{print $2}'
No resources found in kube-system namespace.
Error from server (NotFound): secrets "k8sadmin" not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to execute:

```
kubectl create token eks-admin --namespace kube-system
```

...and this outputs the token.

Source: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/110113